# Refresh a row of updated table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I have a table and with ajax, I updated a row of a table. I need to refresh the modified row of the table when I click on save button.
So far my code is this:

```
function doedit()
{
  var value = {
    'c_firstname': $('#c_firstname').val(),
    'c_lastname': $('#c_lastname').val(),
    'c_gender': $("#c_gender option:selected").html(),
    'c_age': $('#c_age').val(),
    'c_job': $('#c_job').val(),
    'c_address': $('#c_address').val(),
    'c_phone': $('#c_phone').val(),
    'c_mail': $('#c_mail').val(),
    'c_state': $("#c_state option:selected").html(),
    'c_intrest': $("#c_intrest option:selected").html(),
    'c_added_info': $('#c_added_info').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo site_url('customers/updatecustomer'); ?>',
      data: value,
      success: function(resp){
          $('#error').html(resp);
      }
  });

  $('#custtbl').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $('#custtbl').dataTable({ // Cannot initialize it again error
    "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": false },
      null, null, null, null
    ]
  });
}
```

It just do nothing!
The returned value and the updating data table is fine but the refresh is not.
I'm using CodeIgniter by the way. is there any function in it to do it in a short way?

Answer (score 0):

This is use to refresh all the data table that are on a page:

```
$('#custtbl').each(function() {
    dataTable = $(this).dataTable();
    dataTable.fnDraw();
})
```

**Edit:**

```
$('#custtbl').dataTable().fnUpdate('Updated Value Here' , $('Dynamic Table ID Here')[0], 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work too! It just make something like sort the table but doesn't refresh the new value.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your responses :)
I've just used your updated answer like this:
$('#custtbl').dataTable().fnUpdate(value['c_firstname'] , $('cname')[0], 1 );
Which value['c_firstname'] is the value i change and $('cname') is the <td> id but it didn't work.